# How to restart mountd without rebooting the machine?

Tags: nfs

I am setting up a NFS file server, and I have edited the file at `/etc/default/nfs-kernel-server` so that mountd is set to a defined port, rather than a random one.

I tried `sudo service nfs-kernel-server restart` and `sudo service nfs-mountd restart` but no luck, `rpcinfo -p` still shows `mountd` with the random port. If I restart it uses the new port so I know my config file is sane.

Is there a way to restart mountd so it uses the new port without restarting the machine?

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you have to first restart `nfs-config`. This [recommendation](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/NFS#Static_ports_for_NFSv3) did the trick for me:

```
sudo systemctl try-restart nfs-config.service \
                           rpcbind.service \
                           rpc-statd.service \
                           nfs-server.service
```